# Using skills in place of attacking - how can I contribute?

Tags: dnd-5e, combat, skills, combat-maneuver

I'm trying to play a Rogue who doesn't fight directly, but I still want to help out in combat. I've asked my GM if he's ok with me attempting more creative or unusual actions, and he's said yes. (Side note: he proposed that if I'm in a situation in which I *could* have used Sneak Attack he'll be much more likely to allow such actions. I thought this was a pretty clever re-use of a class feature which would otherwise go to waste.)

So now I'm trying to come up with ways of indirectly contributing to combat; regular attacks and face-to-face combat do not suit my character *at all*. I don't want to abuse the GM's generosity, so I'd like to know if the following ideas are reasonable and fair uses of skills/items. If not, how would you rule them?

(Note: my Roguish Archetype lets me make Sleight of Hand checks as a bonus action, so I'll be trying to use this wherever possible.)

- Sleight of Hand to tie an enemy's ankles together while he's distracted, then shove him prone. There are plenty of variations on this idea: attach a lock to his belt, with the lock attached to a chain attached to an anchor (e.g. a tree); or manacle him to the fighter, preventing him from engaging anyone else; or perhaps chain him to the horse, then send the horse running.
- Sleight of Hand to plant something nasty on the enemy. E.g. put a holy symbol on an undead creature (RAW this does nothing, but the GM might rule otherwise). Or strap a flask of explosive/volatile/flammable stuff to the enemy, then use fire breath (I'm a dragonborn) to set it off.
- Lasoo or entangle an enemy with a rope or whip. This might count as a grapple attempt, possibly using Dex instead of Athletics? Similarly, attempting to disarm an enemy with a whip might be an opposed Dex vs Dex or Str check?
- Sleight of Hand to steal something the enemy is using but not holding. E.g. steal a component pouch from a wizard, or a quiver from an archer, or a holy symbol from a cleric.
- Attempt to detach the enemy's armour/equipment (e.g. cutting the straps on his breastplate, lowering his AC). Not sure what kind of check this would be; Sleight of Hand *might* be appropriate if I'm undoing a buckle while he's distracted? Note: it normally takes 1 minute or more to remove armour, but this might not apply if you're basically cutting it apart.
- Keep an enemy (particularly wild animals) at bay with a whip (or perhaps a flaming torch). This might be an Intimidation check? Alternately, I could make an attack roll with the whip, and on a 'hit' deal no damage, instead forcing the enemy to make a fear saving throw.

Additional ideas are welcome, the more creative the better.

Comment: Unfortunately, you've requested a list answer: there can be no single answer that is best for your question, instead you are soliciting discussion and brainstorming. This site is not good at discussion.

Comment: I would suggest that this is an *excellent* question to ask your DM directly. Our rulings are irrelevant, but theirs are quite relevant.

Comment: This sounds like a recipe for disaster. It will likely result in you taking up most of the time each round to hammer out the details of your special unique snowflake actions or not contributing at all...I am sure with a little bit of creativity you can find a way to play to your character's uniqueness within the 5e rules.